# Dynamic styles for different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I need dynamic styles for each user. The problem is such that it is possible to choose between two themes, one static and the other user can change. After change current user theme value will set to sass variable and need precompile. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to rely on pure CSS features in this one rather than compile your SCSS on each request (which will be very inefficient).

Given this base SCSS file:

```
.base-theme {
    .color-main {
      color: $blue-lighter;
    }
    // and so on
}
```

You can use this like this:

```
<p class="color-main"> ... </p>
```

Based on settings stored in the database you can generate an alternative
theme like so:

```
<style>
.alt-theme .color-main {
  color: <%= current_user.colors.main %>;
}
</style>
```

and apply them later like so:

```
<body class="<%= user.has_theme?? 'alt-theme' : 'base-theme'  %>">...</body>
```

Comment: But processing SASS on each request will make your app really, really slow. Asset pipeline is not meant to be used that way in production deployments.

Comment: Yes, but I need write logic for compile sass styles on production after change theme

Comment: You just have to write your theme in CSS and switch the top level class like in my example. You can do this even without SASS.

Comment: I have something like that:

$blue-dark:             #486eac;
$blue-lighter:          #58c9f3;
$brand-brown:           #4a4a4a;
$brand-red:             #d1282d;
$purple-dark:           #8175c7;
$purple-light:          #afa5f1;
$green-dark:            #aec785;
$some_blue:             #1FB5AD;
$moozen_red:            #d90444;

On Settings page I can change color value for each variables ($moozen_red, $some_blue, etc.). This values I save in DB.

Comment: In that case you should generate CSS based on user's settings and inject it with `<style> ` tag. Of course you need to make sure that users can only specify colors etc etc